# Continuity of $(f^{-1})^{r}$, the rth derivative of the inverse of $f$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My textbook says

> If $f:(a,b) \to (c,d)$ is a homeomorphism of class $C^r$, $1\le r\le \infty$, and for all $x \in (a,b)$ we have $f^\prime (x)\neq0$, then $f$ is a $C^r$ diffeomorphism.

The theorem seems extremely trivial at first glance; however, the proof given in the book is not fleshed out and simply says to “use induction” (given this holds for $r=1$). However, I really cannot see how induction would work here.

Suppose we know $(f^{-1})^{(k-1)}$ is continuous, I cannot see how this implies continuity of $(f^{-1})^{(k)}$. In fact, I cannot even seem to prove that $(f^{-1})^{(k)}$ exists only given this fact and that $f$ is class $C^r$. It intuitively should since each step is just repeated applications of the standard derivative rules and since $f^{(r)}$ exists (it even is continuous). It also intuitively should because $f^{-1}$ is just the reflection of $f$ along the x=y line.

However, a fully fleshed out proof doesn’t seem possible unless I give a direct formula for the kth order derivative of $f^{-1}$. In that case, induction is pointless. I feel like I am missing something. Any hints?

Comment: $(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(x))}$. Differentiate $(k-1)$ times.

Comment: how do you prove that this derivative exists given the induction hypothesis? I have also tried this but found it to be dodgy.

Comment: Our induction hypothesis is $f^{-1}(x)$ has a continuous (k-1)th derivative. How does this translate to the $k-1$th derivative of $\frac{1}{f’(f^{-1}(x))}$ ?